# Understanding uninitialised value(s) C

Tags: c, valgrind

I was writing a tokenizer in C and although it works exactly as expected Valgrind throws uninitialized value(s) error. I'm perfectly aware of more than a solution for the code that will fix the problem. Tokenizer is compiled and put into a static library before usage.

The tokenizer in question

```
char ** tokenizer (char *source, const char *delim, int *length){
    char * string;
    int dimension = 2;
    char ** final_tokenization = malloc(sizeof(char *) * dimension);

    string = strtok(source,delim);
    int i = 0;

    while(string != NULL){
        if(i < dimension){
            final_tokenization[i] = string;
            i++;
        }else{
            dimension *= 2;
            final_tokenization = realloc(final_tokenization,sizeof(char *) * dimension);
            if(final_tokenization == NULL){
                return NULL;
            }
            final_tokenization[i] = string;
            i++;
        }
        string = strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
    //length being the final length of final_tokenization
    *length = i;
    return final_tokenization;
}
```

A simple main to test it

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
if(argc == 3){
    int * length;

    char ** string = tokenizer(argv[2],argv[1],length);

    if((*length) == -1 && string == NULL){
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < (*length); i++){
        printf("%s \n",string[i]);
    }

    free(string);
}else{
    exit(-1);
}
return 0;
```

So that a call of `./main " " "token1 token2 token3"` would return one "tokenN" per line.

Now as I understand it when I call `tokenizer(argv[2],argv[1],length)` I'm passing the value of the address of *length* to the function. What is 'inside' said address is unknown (as I've not yet initialized the variable) so reading from it would return some garbage.
More over modifying the main with

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
    if(argc == 3){
        int length;
        
        char ** string = tokenizer(argv[2],argv[1],&length);
[...]
}
```

Does not rise any errors. Why this happens? Shouldn't the result be the same?

Comment: As a side note: If memory re-allocation fails you lose the only pointer to previous buffer – resulting in a memory leak. Correctly re-allocating could look as follows: `void* tmp = realloc(...); if(tmp) { final_tokenization = tmp; } else { free(final_tokenisation); return NULL; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
int * length;

char ** string = tokenizer(argv[2],argv[1],length);
```

The value of `length` is indeterminate, and you are reading that indeterminate value and passing it to a function, and that read is what valgrind is telling you about.

This code will most likely segfault because `tokenizer` will attempt to read that indeterminate value as a pointer and then attempt to dereference it.

In contrast, when you do this:

```
    int length;
    
    char ** string = tokenizer(argv[2],argv[1],&length);
```

The value you're passing to the function is the address of `length` which is well defined.  Then when `tokenizer` dereferences that pointer value and writes a value to the dereferenced pointer, it writes to `length` in `main`.

Comment: I was thrown off by the fact that the code works. So, no guarantee is done that the declaration of `int * length` (even if indeterminate) will be inside a "legal" portion of the allocated memory for my program. Is this a correct conclusion?

Comment: @Linnea117 Yes, dereferencing an invalid pointer triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means no guarantees.  Actually, just reading an indeterminate value can cause UB.